# edit/update java spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, dao

So i am able to create a new user but im stuck.What if i want to update the email of a certain user how am i supposed to do it? Im creating user with save.Is there a way to update it like is this a thing?

```
public User update(@RequestBody User user)
```

`

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(value = "/api/users/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public User create(@RequestBody User user) {

    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    newUser.setPassword(bCryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

    user_dao.save(newUser);

    return newUser;
}
```

Comment: Inside a transaction: `dao.findById(userId).ifPresent(user -> user.setEmail(newEmail));`. You get the persistent, and you update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put (override) a method to update user like this in your service:

```
public void updateUser(User user) {
    User entity = userRepository.findById(user.getId()).orElse(null);
    //Check if the intended record exists. If exists, update it..
    if (entity != null) {
        System.out.println("\nUpdating User- " + user.getUsername() + "\n");
        entity.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        entity.setUseremail(user.getUseremail());
        entity.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    }
    // And finally save it...
    userRepository.save(entity);
}
```